# visual studio 2010 sp1 installation error

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

The installation processed in  a couple of hours then it tells me errors has occurred and needs to rollback.

Here is the error :

```
Action: Performing Action on Exe at Y:\NDP40-KB2468871.exe
Error launching CreateProcess with command line = NDP40-KB2468871.exe /q /norestart /pipe SectionName_1343615874 /log "C:\Users\NHATTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp"Error performing inpage operation.
CreateProcess returned error = Error performing inpage operation.
Original exit code: Y:\NDP40-KB2468871.exe returned non-MSI error code: 0x3e7 - Error performing inpage operation.
Modified exit code: Y:\NDP40-KB2468871.exe returned error code: 0x643 - Fatal error during installation.
Exe (Y:\NDP40-KB2468871.exe) failed with 0x80070643 - Fatal error during installation. .
PerformOperation on exe returned exit code 1603 (translates to HRESULT = 0x80070643)
Action complete
OnFailureBehavior for this item is to Rollback.
```

What is **NDP40-KB2468871.exe** about ?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/b91f22d1-a67b-4415-af47-202ec7696173 has some answers

Answer (score 2):

try reinstall [dotNetFx4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718)

I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look for some kind of damage on the disk or dvd. It happens to me before and that what the cost.

Another posibility is that performing inpage operation occours because the file on the provide by the instalation cd is corrupted.

hope my words can help

Answer (score 1):

My post is unlrelated but mght help others, I got a 0x80070643 error on instaling  visual studio 2010 sp1 on Visual studio express 2010. The error was due to lack of diskspace in C drive.

Such a trivial issue and I overlooked. This could happen to anyone

Sibi